# How to handle Internet Connection in Java class in Android

Tags: android, tracking, internet-connection

how to handle if I have poor internet connection or the if I lost my connection  , I can't handle it in java class,
In Activity I could check the internet Connection but here NO,
So I'm tying to handle the internet connection while tracking

```
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    emailSharedPref = sharedPreferences.getString("email", "");
    Log.e("emailLocation", emailSharedPref);
    Log.i("long", "" + location.getLongitude() + " TIME: " + t.time());
    getAdress(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        URLPath urlPath = new URLPath();
        String serverURL = urlPath.trackEmployee;
        WebServiceRequest request = new WebServiceRequest();
        request.setUrl(serverURL);
        try {
            jsonObject.put("latitude", location.getLatitude());
            jsonObject.put("longitude", location.getLongitude());
            jsonObject.put("street", street);
            jsonObject.put("district", district);
            jsonObject.put("city", city);
            jsonObject.put("time", t.time());
            jsonObject.put("date", t.date());
            jsonObject.put("email", sharedPreferences.getString("email", ""));

            Log.e("jsonLocation", jsonObject.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        request.setRequestBody(jsonObject);
        WebServiceAsyncTask webService = new WebServiceAsyncTask();
        WebServiceRequest[] requestArr = {request};
        webService.execute(requestArr);


}


    public void getAdress(double longt, double lat) {
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(longt, lat, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (addresses != null) {
        street = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
        district = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
        city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
       connection="on";
        Log.d("connection",connection+".."+addresses.toString());
    }else{
        connection="off";
        Log.d("connection",connection);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should write a runnable to runs or checks every 30 seconds for connectivity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678216/android-internet-connectivity-change-listener

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ConnectivityManager` Register a `BroadcastReceiver` with the action `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`. A broadcast event will be sent if the connectivity changes. In the `onReceive` method you can update flags and use these flags for checking before establishing any connection in your method.

eg.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        checkStatus();
    }
};

private void checkStatus(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
    //for airplane mode, networkinfo is null
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    //connection details
    String status = networkInfo.getState().toString();
    String type = networkInfo.getTypeName();
    boolean isConnected = networkInfo.isConnected();
    //update flags here and check them before establishing connection
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    IntentFilter intentFilter =new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver,intentFilter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**a simple method to check if connection to network is present**

u can use it where u wanna jus pass a valid application context

```
 /**
 * check for network connection
 */
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

**note :** this not resolves reachability of network resources you querying

i'm advising to use **HttpURLConnection** to use in AsyncTask and try to handle **SocketTimeoutException** to avoid problems with poor data connection

as @tyler-sebastian proposes:

```
  Handler mHandler;
  public void useHandler() {
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
  }

  private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
          Log.e("Handlers", "Calls");
          /** Do something **/
          mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
      }
  };
```

How to remove pending execution from Handler

- mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);

How to schedule it again

- mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);

Runnable works under UI thread so you can update UserInterface in Handler respective Runnable

then u can use View.sendPostD
[Here u got more example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833908/internet-connectivity-check-fails-in-android)

Comment: what should I pass in the parameter of this function? this class.java not an activity #HELP :D

Comment: @AyaRadwan - any context (in activity ActivityName.this, in fragment getActivity() etc)